# Having trouble with the function in C

Tags: c

I wrote this program to calculate the scalar product and find out the smallest as well as the biggest number (+ there position) of the vector v. Everything works fine except for the lowest_number function. It find the lowest number inside the vector v and the position as well,but when the position is at v[0] ----> at 1 it displays a really long number. I am not sure why this happens. PLease help thank you very much

```
int scalar_produc(int *v,int *w,int n)
{
int i = 0;
int sp;
int sp2 = 0;

for(i= 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sp = v[i] * w[i];
    sp2 = sp2 + sp;
}

return sp2;
}

int lowest_number(int *v,int n)
{
int i = 0;
int low = v[i];
int position;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(v[i] < low)
    {
        low = v[i];
        position = i;
    }
 }

printf("The lowest number is: %d \n", low);
printf("The position of it: %d \n",position+1);
}

int biggest_number(int *v, int n)
{
int i = 0;
int position;
int biggest = v[i];

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(v[i] > biggest)
    {
        biggest = v[i];
        position = i;
    }
}

printf("The biggest number of the vector 'v' is: %d \n",biggest);
printf("The position of the biggest number: %d \n", position+1);
}

int main()
{
int n,i;
int *v,*w;

printf("Enter the number of vectors you would like to enter: \n");
scanf("%d",&n);

v = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) *n);
w = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) *n);

printf("Enter the vectors: \n");
for(i = 0; i < n ;i++)
{
    printf("v[%d]: \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    printf("w[%d]: \n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&w[i]);
}

printf("The scalar product: %d \n",scalar_produc(v,w,n));

lowest_number(v,n);
biggest_number(v,n);

free(v);
free(w);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize `position`.  So if the smallest value is the first value, the value of `position` is undefined.

Initialize it to 0 and it should work.

```
int i = 0;
int low = v[i];
int position = 0;
```

Comment: Minor nitpick; the value of position is indeterminate, and reading that value is undefined behavior.